# Can i resize scene with the size of window JavaFx without binding each widget?

Tags: javafx, resize, scene, stage

In my application, I am switching fxml files for changing the views because I don't properly know the concepts of Scene and Parent roots. all of my fxml files have an AnchorPane(600,400). This is how my start method looks like.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loginpage.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Eye Ratina Scanner");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

this is how I am changing views.

```
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../loginpage.fxml"));
        dashpane.getChildren().setAll(pane) //dashpane is AnchorPane
```

I made the whole app in size of 600:400. Now I want that when I click on the window maximize button, all of the components resize larger and preserve the ratio. two images are attached below to show what's happening.[when i click on maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiyIb.png)

[normal 600:400 view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsRAr.jpg)

now I don't want to bind each button, imageview, anchorpane, text fields, labels, and so on. It will take too long since I have around 42 fxml files. Can we achieve our results by a single snippet? I didn't find any other post having exactly the same issue.

thanks for answering in advance. I totally appreciate your help.

Comment: I personally, like to use `VBox` as the root node. Get `SceneBuilder` and play around with the different `Parent` nodes. Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)

Comment: thanks, @Sedrick for the quick response. I'm learning JavaFX and development. this might help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample layout. It uses a `VBox` as the root. It uses an `AnchorPane`. Inside the `AnchorPane` is a `GridPane`. You will still need to do work to make the `ImageView` and `Label` text grow as the `Stage` gets bigger.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox maxHeight="400.0" prefHeight="75.0" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Dashboard" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Analytics" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Settings" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Notifications" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Logout" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <GridPane hgap="20.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" vgap="20.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="40.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                     <children>
                        <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="25.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! BTW @Sedrick I got my answer in the comment on my question itself. I read about the working of panes. now it is working perfectly.

Comment: I am glad you were able to get it. Good job!